# Prove that union of disjoint finite sets is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint sets which are finite. I am proving that $A\cup B$ is also finite. If either $A$ or $B$ is an empty set $\varnothing$, then $A \cup B$ is either $A$ or $B$. And so $A\cup B$ is a finite set. So, we will assume that $A \ne \varnothing$ and $B \ne \varnothing$. Since $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, there are bijections $f : A \to I_m$ and $g : B \to I_n$. Where, $I_m = \{ i \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, |\, i \leq m \} $ and $I_n = \{ i \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \, | \,i \leq n \} $. Now, I need to prove that $A\cup B$ is also finite. So, I need to come up a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $I_{m+n}$. Now, consider the following binary relation $h$ from $A\cup B$ to $I_{m+n}$.

$$  (x, f(x)) \in h  \, \text{ if } x \in A \\
    (x, m + g(x)) \in h \, \text{ if } x \in B $$

Now, I will prove that this is a function. Let $x \in A \cup B$ be arbitrary. Since they are disjoint, this means that we have two cases. If $x \in A$, we have some $1 \leqslant k_1 \leqslant m$ in $I_m$ such that $f(x) = k_1$. And , if $x \in B$, we have some $1 \leqslant k_2 \leqslant n$ in $I_n$ such that $g(x) = k_2$. So, $m + g(x) = m + k_2$. Now, we have $ k_1 \in I_{m+n}$ and $m + k_2 \in I_{m+n}$. So, it follows that if $x \in A$, then $(x , k_1) \in h$ and if $x \in B$, then $m + k_2 \in h$. So, we proved the existence of some element $y$ in $I_{m+n}$ such that $(x,y) \in h$. Now, suppose there are two such elements $y_1$ and $y_2$. So, we have $(x,y_1) \in h$ and $(x,y_2) \in h$. Now, here if $x \in A$, then $y_1 = f(x)$ and $y_2 = f(x)$. It follows that $y_1 = y_2$. If, $x \in B$, then $y_1 = m + g(x)$ and $y_2 = m + g(x)$. Again, it follows that $y_1 = y_2$. So, now we proved the uniqueness. So, this proves that $h$ is a function. So, we have

$$ h: A\cup B \to I_{m+n} $$

$$ h(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
f(x)  & \text{if $x \in A$} \\
m + g(x) & \text{if $x \in B$} 
\end{cases}
$$

Now, the task is to prove that this function is a bijection. Consider $h(x_1) = h(x_2)$. Now, there are three cases to consider.

Case 1) $x_1, x_2 \in A$

In this case, we have $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and since $f$ is a bijection, we have $x_1 = x_2$.

Case 2) $x_1 \in A$ and $x_2 \in B$

In this case, $f(x_1) = m + g(x_2)$. But $1 \leqslant f(x_1) \leqslant m$ and $1 \leqslant g(x_2) \leqslant n$. It follows that $m < m + 1 \leqslant m + g(x_2) \leqslant m+n$. This means that $f(x_1) \leqslant m < m + g(x_2) = f(x_1)$. This is $f(x_1) < f(x_1)$. This is a contradiction. So, this case is never possible.

Case 3) $x_1, x_2 \in B$

Here, we have $m + g(x_1) = m + g(x_2)$. Cancelling $m$ and noting that $g$ is a bijection, we get that $x_1 = x_2$.

So, it is proven that $h: A\cup B \to I_{m+n}$ is a one to one function. Now, we will prove that its also an onto function.

Let $k \in I_{m+n}$  be some arbitrary element. $ 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m+n $. We will consider two cases here.

Case 1) $ 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m $

Here $k \in I_m$. Since $f$ is an onto function, we have some $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = k$. So, we have $f(x) \in I_{m+n}$  and $ x \in A \cup B$. Using the definition of function $h$, we have $h(x) = f(x) = k$. So, there is some element $x \in A \cup B$ such that $h(x) = k$.

Case 2) $m + 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m+n$

It follows that $ 1 \leqslant k-m \leqslant n$. So, $ k-m \in I_n$ and since function $g$ is an onto function, there is some $x \in B$ such that $g(x) = k-m $. So, $ m + g(x) = k $. Since $ k \in I_{m+n}$ , we have $ m + g(x) \in I_{m+n}$ and since $x \in B$, we have $x \in A \cup B$. So using the definition of function $h$, we have $h(x) = k$.

So, in both cases, it follows that there is some element $y$ in $A\cup B$ such that $h(x) = y$. Which means that function $h: A\cup B \to I_{m+n}$  is an onto function.

This means that the function $h: A\cup B \to I_{m+n}$  is a bijection. We have $ A\cup B \thicksim I_{m+n}$ and so $A \cup B$ is a finite set.

Is this a good proof ?

Thanks

Comment: (+1) The proof is valid, and expressed with commendable precision. I feel that it could be made shorter without losing those qualities - a kind of "refactoring" - and that with less detail it would read more smoothly, but I have no specific suggestions to make at the moment. (I'll try to come back to it later.)

Comment: @Calum Thanks for the input. Somebody here told me to make my proofs as clear as possible. In future, people will visit this and clarity and precision is important.

Comment: I absolutely agree. You've got the most important things right. The rest is a matter of style, and much more art than science.

Comment: Can't you say $\#(A\cup B)\le\#A+\#B$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust good question.

Comment: If one takes this inequality for granted then the proof is obvious. But the OP is *proving* this inequality (actually, equality) for the special case that $A$ and $B$ are finite and disjoint.

Comment: @halrankard2 This confuses me.  Isn't the equality an **immediate** consequence of the two definitions of (1) disjoint and (2) union?  For example, if $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3\}$ and (disjoint) $B = \{b_1, b_2, b_3\}$, then isn't $(A\cup B)$ immediately seen to be $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2, b_3\}.$  Assuming so, and assuming that you *index* each element in the two finite disjoint sets, isn't equality an *immediate* consequence?

Comment: By the way, based on the reactions to my answer, I deleted it.

Comment: @user2661923 The non-immediate consequence is that $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, b_1, b_2, b_3\}$ has size $6$. To do this, you have to re-index the elements $b_1, b_2, b_3$ so that they have indices $4, 5, 6$, which is exactly what is going on in this proof (in slightly different language). Then you have to check that the way you've indexed these elements makes sense.

Comment: @user2661923 First, my comments were not meant to suggest you delete (actually the opposite). My goal was to clarify the connection between the OP's proof and yours. The basic situation is this. On the one hand one can say "It is obvious/immediate that if $A$ has $m$ elements and $B$ has $n$ elements, and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $A\cup B$ has $m+n$ elements." But this is not a rigorous proof. First you need to a rigorous definition for "$A$ has $m$ elements", and the OP is using the standard: there is a bijection from $A$ to $\{1,\ldots,m\}$. (1/2)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Interesting response, thanks.

Comment: So now the statement translates to: If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, there is a bijection from $A$ to $\{1,\ldots,m\}$, and a bijection from $B$ to $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then there is a bijection from $A\cup B$ to $\{1,\ldots,m+n\}$. This is what the OP proves. Is the proof overly detailed? Maybe. But all I’m saying is that one cannot replace a rigorous *proof* of $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$ by our intuition that it is correct. In other words, no it’s not immediate. You have to construct the bijection. (2/2)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I surmised, based on the reactions, that my analysis was **circular.**  In effect, I was assuming to be true just what the OP apparently proved to be true.  That made my answer inappropriate, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Let

$$f:A\to[1,n],$$

$$g:B\to[1,m],$$
and define
$$h:A\cup B\to[1,n+m]:\begin{cases}e\in A\to f(e),\\e\in B\to g(e)+n.\end{cases}$$

Reciprocally,

$$h^{-1}(i):[1,n+m]\to A\cup B:\begin{cases}i\in[1,n]\to f^{-1}(i),\\i\in[n+1,n+m]\to g^{-1}(i-n).\end{cases}$$

is always defined and $h$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 3):

If there are *bijections* $f:A\to [1,n]$ and $g:B\to [1,m]$, there is a *bijection* $g':B\to[n+1,n+m]$.

Then there is a *function* $h:A\cup B\to [1,n+m]$ by the natural mapping of the elements of $A$ and $B\setminus A$ to their images by the respective bijections $f$ and $g'$.

From this function $h$ you can define a finite bijection $h'$ by dropping the naturals with no preimage. (Hence disjointness is not even required.)

---

This was the long way to say

$$\#(A\cup B)\le\#A+\#B.$$

---

It does not take much to improve the result as

$$\#(A\cup B)+\#(A\cap B)=\#A+\#B.$$

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I need your definition of the cardinal of a set. Or for the initial question, the definition of a finite set.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: then the step to the bijection of $A\cup B$ with $\{1,\cdots n+m\}$ is microscopic.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing; I thought you were saying the first part of your question should be replaced by the second part.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: as is often the case, the question doe not state "what" you are allowed or disallowed to use.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: the problem can become "more fun" by taking the definition: a finite set is such that there is no bijection between itself and a proper subset.